# Sublime Text 2 HTML syntax highlighting issue

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2

I am having a problem with the syntax highlighting for HTML (and plaintext) in Sublime Text 2,
as it only grays out the lines as in the image.

[image]

Whenever I shift to Python, JavaScript, and other languages, the highlighting works fine.
I am new to Sublime Text 2, so it is probably an easy answer, but I did not know how to formulate the issue without showing an image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont't think it is a problem, it's just how the theme "All Hallow's Eve" works:
You can change the this color inside this block: (Preferences->Browse Packages>Color Scheme - Default->All Hallow's Eve)

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Text base</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>background</key>
            <string>#434242</string> #THIS IS GRAY COLOR YOU WANNA CHANGE.
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FFFFFF</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem; it seems like the color scheme "All Hallow's Eve" is not
working very well on HTML, so I simply changed the color scheme.